How to use Wordpress Elementor elementor/document/save/data hook?
I am trying to change the text of the page saved in the wordpress elementor editor, but server error occure. What do I do wrong?
function my_custom_elementor_save( $post_id, $editor_data ) {

}
add_action( 'elementor/document/save/data', 'my_custom_elementor_save', 10, 2);

Error:
Uncaught Exception: Return value of Elementor\Modules\ContentSanitizer\Module::sanitize_content() must be of the type array, null returned in /home/plussize/public_html/demo/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/content-sanitizer/module.php on line 28

Could you please share the screenshot of the text and error you are getting so I can take closer look.

@NarendraSishodiya Updated the post

For this I suggest you to add the check in the function.  if ( !is_array( $editor_data ) ) {         return;     } so if data is not array it returns.
